# Why is it possible to pass an argument of another type to a function?

Tags: c, function

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void function (char arg)
{
    // function's content
}

int main(void)
{
    long double x = 1.23456;

    function(x);
}
```

I'm giving the function an argument it is not supposed to get. Why does it not cause an error?

Comment: The compiler may give a warning such as *conversion from 'long double' to 'char', possible loss of data*.

Comment: @WeatherVane it does not, I tried two different compilers

Comment: You can (and should) increase the warning level, this was from MSVC. In gcc `-Wall`.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what options are provided on the command line?

Comment: @MichaelBurr the one from repl.it IDE (I don't think it's possible to manipulate the compiler there) and the other is mingw-w64 (all the parameters were set by default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's converted implicitly.

In the context of an assignment, argument passing, a `return` statement, and several others, an expression of any arithmetic type is implicitly converted to the type of the target if the target type is also arithmetic. In this case, the `double` argument is implicitly converted to `char`. (That particular conversion rarely makes sense, but it's valid as far as the language is concerned.)

Note that this implicit conversion is *not* done for variadic arguments (for example arguments to `print` after the format string), because the compiler doesn't know what the target type is. `printf("%d\n", 1.5)` doesn't convert `1.5` from `double` to `int`; rather it has undefined behavior.

There are also some rules for evaluating expressions with operators of different types. I won't go into all the details here, but for example given:

```
int n = 42;
double x = 123.4;
```

if you write `n + x` the value of `n` is promoted (implicitly converted) from `int` to `double` before the addition is performed.

Comment: Thanks, yet I've already heard of typecasting when dealing with values of different types. One more question, is it safe/eligible to pass arguments of other types without typecasting and yield this work to implicit convertion?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Kaiyaha To clarify the terminology, C doesn't use the word "typecasting". A *conversion* takes a value of some type and yields a value of a (different) type. A *cast* is an explicit conversion, represented by a cast operator consisting of a type name in parentheses. There are implicit conversions. There are no implicit casts.

Comment: @Kaiyaha The conversions that are done implicitly are usually reasonably safe as long as the source value can be represented in the target type. In some cases you can lose precision or have an oveflow (with varying results depending on the types). For example, if a function expects an `int` argument, passing it `6.02e23` will implicitly convert to `int`, and the overflow results in undefined behavior. (So don't do that.)

Comment: I have to say that, after writing C for nearly 30 years, I rarely see things in C that surprise me; but this blew my mind. I was amazed that `gcc` passed the construction in this question, even with `-Wall`. I needed explicitly to add `-Wconversion` to detect it. I will be doing that in future. Amazing.

Comment: @KevinBoone The constraints on simple assignment ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) 6.5.16.1) allow for cases where "the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has arithmetic type". The constraints on argument passing, return statements, et al refer to that section.

Comment: @KeithThompson I met "typecasting" in several sources, why not to use it?

Comment: @Kaiyaha The C standard uses the word "cast", never "typecast". Why use a non-standard term? What's the advantage of "typecasting" over "casting"? (Note that "typecasting" is also something that happens to actors.)

Comment: @KeithThompson personally to me it seems more clarifying since it is clear straight away what the 'cast' is about. Maybe that makes no difference to some experienced geeks, but that is my first glance at the subject

Comment: @Kaiyaha The word "cast" is unambiguous if you're talking about C. The word "typecast" might conceivably be a synonym either for "cast" or for "conversion". I won't tell you not to use "typecast" (I have no authority), but I avoid it myself, and I think most experienced C programmers do as well.

Comment: @Keith Thompson -- I'm not disputing the right of the language to be the way it is. I'm just surprised that `gcc` doesn't warn about it, even with settings that provide a whole bunch of other petty, pedantic complaints. And, I suppose, because a comparable construction in Java won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the `double` type is implicitly converted to a `char`.

Comment: @ShaneReilly you said 'in your example'. Any other options?

Comment: There are lots of data types that can be implicitly converted from one type to another. An example of something that would *not* compile however, would be using `function(char* arg)` and trying to pass a `double` to it.